# Swipe Delete not working on first time swipe

Tags: ios, swipe

Am developing Music Player App. In that app I added functionality to delete a song from Playlist while swiping. This feature is working in all pages properly except one page. The problem is delete button will be shown after swiping the row three or more times. This problem occurs on only one page, in all other pages delete button will be shown when we swipe the cell first time. I don't know what to do. Anybody help me?

Comment: Are there other functionalities in that view that block UI? Are you sure the swipe gesture is added at the right moment?

Comment: didSelectRow for that Tableview is working properly that mean no other functionality blocks that UI. I don't add swipe gesture , i just use the UITableview's default swipe delete fucntionality and I have implemented the commiEditingStyle method

Comment: What else is different between that page and the others?